# How do I perform an operation on only the int part of lists?

Tags: python, string, list, int

I'm trying to complete this assignment for a class. The instructions say to:

> `L` is a list of lists. The first item in each
>   sublist is a student name and the rest of the items in the  sublist
>   are grade values (`float` or `int`). Return a new list of lists where
>   each sublist has length 2 of the form `[student_name (str), average grade (float)]`
>
> ```
> >>> average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])
> [['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
> ```

The problem that I'm having with my code is that I'm trying to be able to enter in the lists, but only find the average of the integers. So far I have this:

```
for int in ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Joe']:
    return (map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]), map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]), map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]))
```

But when I enter in even only one list, I get this:

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I'm not sure what to do here. Any help?

Comment: I'm sorry that your instructor thinks that lists are the only data types available in Python.

Comment: I bet slicing would be useful here.

Comment: Do not use `int` as a variable name, as it will hide the builtin `int` type/function. The best approach would be to define a function `average_grade` and then test it with the line proposed in the problem statement, `average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])`, and see if your result matches the expected. You would just need to add each sublist's members from the first and divide by the list length minus one (the name). You probably don't need `map` here.

Comment: You could translate the list of lists into a "proper" data structure, like a list of dictionaries and parse that just to show your teacher that you disagree with his implementation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deconstruct each of the sublists.

```
def average_grade(grade_db):
    averages = []
    for student_grades in grade_db:
        name = student_grades[0]
        grades = student_grades[1:]
        # proceed to update results
    return averages

results = average_grade([['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]])
```

The first time through the loop on the given call, `student_grades == ['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90]`, the second time through `student_grades == ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70]`, and so on. Thus, the first time through the loop, `name == 'Bob'` and `grades == [56, 80, 72, 90]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
def average_grade(L):
    return [[el[0], float(sum(el[1:]))/len(el[1:])] for el in L]
```

This is the list comprehension approach.

Iterate over your list of lists `L`: for each element `el` create a new list with first element being `el[0]` (name), and second element being the average. The average is computed using `float(sum(x))/len(x)`, using the sliced list `el[1:]`. The slicing `el[1:]` means take a sublist of `el` starting from index 1 up to the end. `float()` is needed here since the `sum()` can be `int` if all the elements are `int`.

Comment: Providing a full solution without any word of explanation isn't going to help the OP.

Comment: Edited my answer. I'm aware it might not be suitable for beginners, but IMHO more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Possible implementation below:

```
test = [['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]]


def mean(numbers):
    'Takes a list of numbers as argument and returns a float as their mean'
    return float(sum(numbers)) / max(len(numbers), 1)


def average_grade(list_of_students):
    'Takes the lists of students as arguments and returns a list of lists containing the name and average grade'
    # We build an empty list to populate as we parse the list of students
    students = []
    # Parse each sublist of the list of students
    for student in list_of_students:
        # We add to the students list a new list made of:
        # element 0 is the first element of each sublist, meaning the name
        # element 1 is the result of applying the mean function over a list of floats created from each entry in the grades list
        students.append([student[0], mean([float(i) for i in student[1:]])])
    # And we return the students list
    return students

print(average_grade(test))
```

Possible bugs with this implementation:

What if one of your grades cannot be converted to a float? Hint -> TypeError 
on cast in line 18.

What if you have an empty list of grades for one of your entries?

What if you have a missing name?

What if your entry data is not a list?

What if that list is completely empty?

Possible teacher questions: 
Why would you instantiate an empty list inside your average function? Why not just declare it outside? Hint: take the line outside of the function then call average_grade() twice and see what happens.

Why do you cast to float before you calculate the mean? Here it's done to avoid calculating the mean of non string/int values. If one such value is in the list of grades, the script will just error out with a TypeError. You could circumvent this by surrounding the entire cast in a try/catch clause and either stop execution when you encounter an unexpected value or just discard it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the MOST efficient way to do this in Python but I believe it will make it more clear for beginners:

```
final_list = []
for sublist in lists:
    new_list = sublist[0] # Student name is always in the first index
    new_list.append(sum(sublist[1:]) / float(len(sublist[1:]))) # Take an average of the rest of the sublist and append it to the new list
    final_list.append(new_list) # Append the new_list e.g. ['Bob', 74.5] to the final list
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `new_list = []` ?

Comment: But isn't that going to make beginners think that it **is** necessary when they see this?

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name as it will hide the builtin `list` type. **edit:** OK, `sublist` is better.

Comment: @JonathanPorter There's explicit, and then there's unnecessary code. If the reader doesn't already know that `sublist[0]` is a list, then `new_list = []` isn't going to be any more enlightening; their just going to see that the line is unnecessary because it is immediately changed. There are better ways to provide type hints in Python.

Comment: But there's nothing implicit about creating a list with one element.

Comment: I was just going to say, Jonathan, you would be better off stealing two lines from the answer chepner provided, starting: `name=student_grades[0]`. Now that's what **I** call explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the attempted solution (in the question) is doing:

```
for int in ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Joe']:
  return (map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]), map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]), map(L[sum(int)/len(int)]))
```

1. It is iterating over names 'Bob', 'Alice' and 'Joe'
2. At first iteration the value of the variable that is named as `int` (BTW `int` is a python keyword, so consider choosing a better name) has value 'Bob'
3. At this point the your return statement translates to something equivalent of 
   `return (map(L[sum('Bob')/len('Bob'), map(L[sum('Bob')/len('Bob'), map(L[sum('Bob')/len('Bob'))`

Notice that you are trying to sum a string object. This raises the TypeError

`builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Now, to dive deeper, where is the `'int'` type coming in, in the above error. The `sum` function is essentially trying to do this:

```
S = 0
S = S + 'B'
S = S + 'o'
S = S + 'b'
return S
```

As you can see, we can't add up an integer and a string. It makes no sense.

Here is an example of an approach that might work:

`map(lambda x: [x[0],sum(x[1:])/(float)(len(x)-1)], L)`

The above solution will iterate over each item in L. An item here is a sublist like `['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90]`. Then, the `lambda` function maps this sublist to 
`['Bob', sum([56, 80, 72, 90])/(float)(len(['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90])-1)]`.

Each iteration produces a mapped list as above and that's one of the potential solutions. HTH.

Comment: i wrote this lines 2 hours ago but my net was not working that time :)

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. @dgumo you might want to expound on your answer. The question posed is about understanding type operations, though your answer might solve the assignment in one line. The student would benefit from a broader understanding of types and list operations.

Comment: @Matt Thank you for pointing out the issue with the answer. Apologies for the terse answer. Edited. Hopefully, useful now :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension which is one line solution :

> with loop:

```
your_data=[['Bob', 56, 80, 72, 90], ['Alice', 60, 88, 44, 70], ['Joe', 44, 100, 80, 60, 50]]

print([[item[0],sum(item[1:])/len(item[1:])] for item in your_data])
```

output:

```
[['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
```

without loop :

If you don't want loop you can try with lambda :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:[x[0],sum(x[1:])/len(x[1:])],your_data)))
```

output:

```
[['Bob', 74.5], ['Alice', 65.5], ['Joe', 66.8]]
```